# Access Angular Scope from your own script by ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I bet there's an easy answer to this but no matter what I search for I can't come up with something that will work within the page I'm trying to help someone with.

They have an Angular application on a page they didn't develop that uses ngTagsInput and want to add some functionality within their own script. From the Chrome console this is very easy such as clearing existing tags or adding a custom like this:

```
$scope.Tags.push( { Name: "29-Testing" } )
```

The problem is $scope.Tags returns as `undefined` within the script I'm helping them with. I've found a number of methods that seem capable of grabbing a scope but they are all based on `getElementById` and as this element has no `ID` I'm looking for a way to set `$scope.Tags` via the `ng-model="Tags"` which is the only really unique portion of the page.

Gotta say I was pretty excited when I showed him what he wanted working from the console, now I have to make it work within a script!

Thanks for any advice and hope I just didn't know what to search for...again!

Comment: Do you not have access to the AngularJS controller scripts? The controller will likley contain the `$scope.tags` definition and this is where the context would be for changing its values.

Comment: you can grab the element, using document.querySelector for instance, and then run 'angular.element(..captured-element..).scope()` to access the scope. see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#retrieving-scopes-from-the-dom-